# Could not Navigate to a Hidden Folder

Tags: 18.04, virtualbox

I have run the code below:

```
 python -m site --user-site
```

and the output is

```
 /home/aegono/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

But when I list all hidden folders in `/home/aegono`, I could not see `.local` folder.

```
 cd /home/aegono/
 ls -a
```

[image]

`.local` folder seems not existing.

[image]

How shall I navigate to the `site-packages` folder?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try `$cd /home/aegono/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` ?